# iOS apps sharing assets

Tags: iphone, ios4

Hey All,
I have an upcoming project that will require the same assets (images, video, audio) be used across multiple applications. Is is possible on iOS to share assets this way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not - each application lives in its own sandbox. It's part of the underlying iOS security system that apps can't share resources or assets. You'll have to bundle all your assets required into each individual app (unless you are prepared to host your assets in a single place online and have the app download them).

Answer (score 1):

In general there are so many ways to share datas and strings between apps
 those are as follows.

> - UIDocumentInteractionController
> - UIActivityViewController
> - Shared Keychain Access
> - Custom URL Scheme
> - Web Service
> - iCloud API

Each feature has its own pros and cons

Go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20042701/730807) to know more.