# Rewarding users for downloading other games

Tags: iphone, ios, reward-system

I have multiple games on the iOS app store. I want to give users free game coins when they download any of my other games. Is there a way to do this without setting up a server? In case a server is the only option, what is the best way to do so!

Comment: I don't know this for certain, but I could imagine there might be a way to solve this using the game center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a useful link: [Share data between two or more iPhone applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425706/share-data-between-two-or-more-iphone-applications)

Basically, I believe the options are:

1. Use `UIPasteBoard` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12957258/727817). Sample code [here](http://kmithi.blogspot.ro/2012/03/sharing-data-among-ios-applications.html).
2. Use [custom URL schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9425834/727817)
3. Using [keychain](http://shaune.com.au/ios-keychain-sharing-data-between-apps/)
4. Using a server - the first time an app is opened it would send a request to the server to notify that the app was installed; the app offering credits would send a request (probably when it becomes active) to check if the user has downloaded any new apps.