# Firemonkey iOS share data

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

Please do not mark this question as duplicated or already answered.  I specifically need help with the Delphi, and there is NO answers with regards to the code (if I am wrong please provide me with it).
Also please note that I am looking for help with XE5 as specified in my tags.

I need help with code on sharing data between Applications on iOS.  I have read the theory on this at  [Share data between two or more iPhone applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425706/share-data-between-two-or-more-iphone-applications).

I now get the idea about how to share files, but I cannot find anything with regards to sharing data with Firemonkey.  I did find some information on File sharing using Flexcell by TMS, but that is only related to opening document in other files.

I specifically want to share an XML like document between apps so that apps can communicate data via the XML (read and write data from the xml).

Has anyone been able to successfully do this using Firemonkey 3 and XE5?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Indy components ? a idtcpserver on one app and idtcpclient on the other app you can send what ever you like between them.

Comment: Unfortunately, the tcpclient and tcpserver is not compatible with iOS.

Comment: Thanks... do you know how to access the calendar and events doe delphi xe5 Android I cant find any code samples :(