# How to acess one appliction sqlite database in another application

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have one application in that i created the sqlite database and store in the document directory. Now i open other application from existing application and in that i want to access the existing database path. how can i do this can any one help me. I write the code below for open another application and calling the document directory. But it gets the the wrong document directory path.

==============

```
UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSString *ourPath = @"POSRetail://";
    NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ourPath];
    if ([ourApplication canOpenURL:ourURL])
    {

        databasePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"databasePath : %@",databasePath);
        NSString *filePath = [databasePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testapp.sqlite"];

        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];

        if(fileExists)
        {

            NSMutableString *strRecord =[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
            //Retrieve the values of database
            const char *dbpath = [filePath UTF8String];
            if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &sdatabase) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                // NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM employee"];
                // const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
                const char *query_stmt = "Select * from info";
                sqlite3_stmt *statement;
                //const char *query_stmt = "Select * from sqlite_master where type='table'";
                NSMutableArray *arrTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(sdatabase, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

                        [arrTemp addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];
                        [strRecord appendFormat:@"%@,",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];
                        [arrTemp addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]];
                        [strRecord appendFormat:@" %@,",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]];
                        [arrTemp addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]];
                        [strRecord appendFormat:@" %@,",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]];
                        [arrTemp addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)]];
                        [strRecord appendFormat:@" %@\n",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)]];
                    }

                    NSLog(@"arrTemp : %@",arrTemp);
                    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                }
                else
                {
                    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(sdatabase));
                }
                sqlite3_close(sdatabase);
            }
            else
            {
                sqlite3_close(sdatabase);
                NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(sdatabase));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"SQLITE DATABASE NOT AVAILABLE");
        }
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Receiver Not Found" message:@"The Receiver App is not installed. It must be installed." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As if you want to access other `iOS App` data  then Two Words From `Apple`

`Not Possible`

As `iOS` App is work in `SandBox Environment` sharing data between applications so sharing data directly through the `file system` is not possible, But there is also certain ways provided for sharing data review this like

**[Custom URL Scheme:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)**

- the `iOS programming` guide now has a section on passing data between
  apps by having one app claim a certain `URL prefix` and then having
  other apps reference that `URL`. For this point of your you can look
  this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50). And [Good Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425706/share-data-between-two-or-more-iphone-applications) on `SO` related
  this Question.

**[UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html)**

- A document interaction controller, along with a delegate object,
  provides in-app  support for managing user interactions with files in
  the local system.  For example, an email program might use this class
  to allow the user to  preview attachments and open them in other
  apps. Use this class to present  an appropriate user interface for
  previewing, opening, copying, or printing a  specified file.

**[iCloud API:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/Introduction.html)**

- iCloud is a free service that lets users access their personal
  content on all 
         their devices—wirelessly and automatically via Apple ID. iCloud does this by 
         combining network-based storage with dedicated APIs, supported by full 
         integration with the operating system. Apple provides server infrastructure, 
         backup, and user accounts, so you can focus on building great iCloud-enabled 
     apps.

**NOTE : No Idea With Jail Break `iOS` Device I Got the Reference [This Great Document.](http://enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/)**

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to access the data of another application directly.
Because each application is running on a sandbox environment.

But you can do it, how ?

You need to use `iCloud`. You can share the data stored the iCloud between apps, so store your database file in iCloud.

**References:**

You can find a tutorial on iCloud here : [iCloud Programming](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1) 
I cloud Data sharing is described here : [iCloud Data Sharing](http://blog.codiform.com/2011/06/will-icloud-allow-data-sharing-between.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible at all, each app runs in its own VM, its impossible for other apps to access data of each other, unless the data is written on a shared space like SD card itself.

Comment: What you mean by SD Card ? AFAIK, there is no option for SD card in iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You can jailbreak your devices, then use some jailbreak development library that can give you each application's sandbox folder, or you can iterate the Application folder yourself.