# How can I share an object between processes?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, multithreading, theos

I'm making a tweak for jailbroken iPhones, and I have an object that I need to share between two processes. Currently, it is null in one process and contains information in another. How can I get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you currently sharing it?

Comment: Currently, it's just a global variable. When I log it from one process, it holds info, and when I log it from another process, it's null.

Comment: And you've no idea why that's the case?

Comment: Well, I know that it's because the processes don't share the same memory space and therefor don't share the object's data, however what I *don't* know is how to actually share that object so they *do* share it.

Comment: You could try Distributed Objects.

Comment: Ugh. I just did a bit of research on distributed objects and they seemed like *exactly* what I was looking for, but unfortunately NSConnection isn't available on iPhone :(

Comment: This question has already been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425706/share-data-between-two-or-more-iphone-applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use NSUserDefaults:

Write them to memory as:

```
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:variableName]forKey:@"giveItAName"];
```

Make sure it saves with:
`[NSUserDefaults synchronise];`

And them use them again like this:

```
NSNumber *number = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey@"giveItAName"]doubleValue];
```

I also think you should look up what a global is, you don't seem to know how to use them

Hope this helps