# Today Extension (App Groups)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager, today-extension

I have been browsing the Apple Documentation for hours now and there is so little on the Today Extension, so I just can't get to the bottom of this problem...

I am trying to access a plist file stored in the `NSDocumentDirectory` but am having no luck. The today extension is all set up correctly with a separate target in the project and my bundle identifier starts with 'group.' but I get a null value every time?

This is my code...

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.ORGANISATION.APPNAME.wigit"];
NSString *string = [storeURL.path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataFile.plist"];
NSMutableArray *content = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to access file in NSDocumentDirectory from the app extension?

Comment: @Joe Barbour Please follow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425706/share-data-between-two-or-more-iphone-applications) maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to share data between the AppExtension and the containing app. By default your extension and its containing app have no direct access to each other’s containers. So the `NSDocumentDirectory` of your app will not be accessible form the extension. You could use `NSUserDefaults` to share the data.

Read it here [Sharing Data with Your Containing App](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1)

Comment: That was my question yes. So there is no way to access any file within the documents directory via the extension because there is no direct access supported?

Comment: Ya. AFAIK not possible. You have to use NSUserDefaults that what i find on the apple docs