# How do I change my app icon after deployment?

Tags: ios, icons

I'm working on my first app and I'm offering a lite version. The standard version features will be unlocked by changing a value in a plist after a user purchase. I also have an app icon for my standard version that is different than the one for the lite version. How can I update my app icon after the user purchases the standard version?

I know I can't change it from within the app...

Comment: In short: No, you can't .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't change the App Icon, except your App is a Newsstand App.

For Newsstand App, you can do the followings:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app setNewsstandIconImage:newsstandImage];
```

Alternatively, you can provide an iTunes redeem code to user, to let them download the "standard" version of your App in App Store. Still, the user has to remove the "lite" version himself. (this is not a user-friendly way, though)

Comment: So whats the best user-friendly way to do it? Aren't there other apps that have a lite icon that changes when the user purchases the full version? And if the user has saved data in the LITE version, can I not keep that data for the full version?

Comment: You should think about the user-friendly way yourself, as it's different for every apps. Is there any apps working like this in iOS platform? I don't think so. For your last question, you can share the data between 2 apps (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425706/share-data-between-two-or-more-iphone-applications))