# How to pass objects/data between my iOS applications

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8

I have an existing iOS application on the app store, and I am building a new companion app to work with this existing app.

I need to pass objects/data from this new app to my existing app when a certain action is taken. The behaviour I'm looking for is very similar to AirDrop but the data is passed to another app on the same device.

The objects I want to pass locally between apps are simply NSObject's.

Comment: I mean, are they storing info on the same server?

Comment: where exactly the data is stored? in the Iphone or web server? what kind of data you need to pass? Is it objects of obj c or photo or videos?

Comment: No there is no server involved here. Just and array of NSObject's. Air Drop works the same way. All I'm looking for here is a local solution.

Answer (score 2):

As per your comment you wants to share NSObjects between your iOS apps. The best approach would be "Custom URL Schemes". But in this approach you may need to add or re write some parts in your old iOS App as well.

checkout [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425706/share-data-between-two-or-more-iphone-applications) for more info on implementing custom url scheme and history of sharing data between ios apps.

Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) for sharing data is also available.

If your app supports greater than iOS 8 you can also use the new feature called "App Group Functionality"

Comment: I didn't ask the question, but I learned something. Thank you!