# Create a directory and store files inside it in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, directory, nsurl

i am creating a directory so that i can save temp videos onto it as TempVideos is a folder now my video clips will be inside the folder...

```
func createTempDirectoryToStoreVideos(){
    var error: NSError?
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = paths[0]
    tempVideoPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("TempVideos")

    if (!NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(tempVideoPath!)) {

        NSFileManager.defaultManager() .createDirectoryAtPath(tempVideoPath!, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: &error)

    }

}
```

Now in these directory i want to store the videos as

```
   func saveCompressVideoToTempDirectory(var compressedVideoUrl:NSURL?){

    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: compressedVideoUrl!)
    var error:NSError?
    var success = data?.writeToFile(tempVideoPath!, options: NSDataWritingOptions.AtomicWrite, error: &error)
    println(error)

    if let temp = success{

        if temp {

            println("success")

        }else{

            println("not valid ")

        }

    }

}
```

Howver i get error as

> Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0x17407f6c0
>   {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F1140A9F-8D16-444B-8679-9ED1AD3F5E6A/Documents/TempVideos,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x17424a320 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Is
>   a directory"})

Comment: You have posted the same function twice.

Comment: sorry..i edited that...you can see how frustated i am :)

Comment: The error message is quite clear: tempVideoPath is the path to the "TempVideos" *directory* and you are trying to write to that instead of creating a file *inside* that directory.

Comment: Replace `tempVideoPath!` in `writeToFile(tempVideoPath!` with tempVidePath+videoName.

Comment: data?.writeToFile(tempVideoPath!, options: NSDataWritingOptions.AtomicWrite, error: &error) ///well why doesnot this method save  file in the directory??

Comment: You `writeToFile` and pass in the `tempVideoPath`, therefore it fails because it is a directory

Comment: well the method is saying to put the data inside the directory no??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try `createFileAtPath` for that?

```
func createFileAtPath(_ path: String,
         contents data: NSData?,
       attributes attr: [String : AnyObject]?) -> Bool
```

The same thing concerns `writeToFile`:

```
func writeToFile(_ path: String,
     options writeOptionsMask: NSDataWritingOptions) throws
```

where, look out, *path* is

> The location to which to write the receiver's bytes. If `path` contains
>   a tilde (~) character, you must expand it with
>   `stringByExpandingTildeInPath` before invoking this method.

You should write this:

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
var dirpath: String = paths[0] as String
let filepath = dirpath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("myOwnData.mov")
```

Comment: ok i did as you said    var success = data?.writeToFile("\(tempVideoPath!)\(videoNumberPostfix)", options: NSDataWritingOptions.AtomicWrite, error: &error)...but these saves file outside of the directory?

Comment: @swiftBUTCHER well, the filename should be append to the directory's path.

Comment: @swiftBUTCHER let me know if everything is okay.