# SPM and images in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, swift-package-manager

I have problem during developing my project. I've decided to switch to SPM and almost everything is working as expected, but I'm fighting with one thing quite long and I don't know that should I do.

I have couple of packages. One of them is UI package which contains some images, custom implementations of some reusable screens etc, but most important is that it contains some icons that are being used around other packages.

I have second package, which is covering implementation of one of part of my application. In this we can find all screens connected with this functionality, and also it has some storyboards inside (in the future I will rewrite this storyboards to code version). And there I have an problem - since storyboards cannot load images from other bundle during runtime so even if in Xcode I can see that storyboard has an image and this image is from other package, during runtime it is not loading. When I was using Pods for that, I had a little script which was creating reference between Assets folder form UI framework to FunctionalityFramework and after this operation images were loading properly (similar like described there: [Storyboard, UIImageView. Load image from bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245422/storyboard-uiimageview-load-image-from-bundle))

But how I can achieve that with SPM? I cannot make reference between two packages and their folders. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 5.3 added improvements to SPM to provided resources, so one way to accomplish what you're asking is to have your swift package  vend the images and then load those images via the `UIViewController`  that backs the Storyboard view.

Apple's documentation for bundling resources can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/bundling_resources_with_a_swift_package).

Here's the highlights:

Make sure that your swift package has resources declared for a target:

```swift
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "MyLibrary",
        resources: [
            .process("Resources")
            // This will process the /Sources/MyLibrary/Resources directory.
        ]
    ),
]
```

When resources are declared, a new `Bundle` reference becomes available that references the package resources. The `Bundle.module` reference can be used to load and provide the images. In your swift package, you can specify the images available with something like:

```swift
#if canImport(UIKit)
import UIKit

public extension UIImage {
    static var myImage: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "ImageName", bundle: Bundle.module, compatibleWith: nil)
}
#endif
```

Now, in your `UIViewController`, you should be able to import your package, and assign the image to an `@IBOutlet`:

```swift
import UIKit
import MyLibrary

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad
        imageView.image = .myImage
    }
}
```

---

Another approach is to provide a custom `UIImageView` class through your library that will load images from the `Bundle.module`. This can be implemented through the Storyboard, but you will loose the ability to see the image in-place. For example, If I declared this class in my swift package:

```swift
public class AppIconImageView: UIImageView {
    @IBInspectable var imageName: String = "" {
        didSet {
            image = UIImage(named: imageName, in: Bundle.module, compatibleWith: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I could then use that class in a Storyboard. Provide the name of the image that you want to have displayed via the `imageName` runtime property. (You can then unset the 'image' setting in Interface Builder.)

[image]

Like I mentioned, the image will not show in the Storyboard (`@IBDesignable` in other modules is often tricky), but when run, the package resource should load.

Comment: Not really :) I know, that by code I can load images from different bundles - question is if there is an possibility to load images directly into storyboards from other bundles, since your solution (and one I've tried) force me to spend lot of time to update all storyboards (I know, best option will be to rewrite them to codebase, but this is an acquired project :) ) In other words - how I can force storyboard to load all images which are accessible in Xcode storyboard editor :)

Comment: @KamilWalas gotcha. I've added an additional approach that would allow you to do what you want through the storyboard, but with some design limitations.

Comment: Yea, I will go with this solution, but I thought that there will be an opportunity to load images without this changes. Thank you very much :)