# Linkedin iOS SDK for Login Authentication w/ Native Linkedin App

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi, linkedin-ios-sdk

I recently downloaded "Linkedin Groups" and "Linkedin Sales Navigator" on iOS and the login experience was great.

When I loaded up the app (Linkedin Groups), the first onboarding screen already knew who I was and presented me with an option that had my Linkedin Profile Photo and said "Continue as Anthony".

I am curious to know how Linkedin does this and if we have the ability to create this feature as well?  I'm assuming they were able to pull (my avatar and name) from my already installed native Linkedin app (the regular Linkedin app)?

I am currently building an app and will be using Linkedin SDK for Login Auth but can't seem to find where I can access this information "pre-auth" of my app.

Any thoughts?  Or can only Linkedin do this because they "own" both apps?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the way that LinkedIn have done it but have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425706/share-data-between-two-or-more-iphone-applications . Might help