# disable internet on other ios apps

Tags: ios

I'd like to create a very simple app to block internet access for certain app's between 7PM and 7AM on my iPhone.
However the mobile phone & imessage should stay usable, so it's no airplane modus.
This is to have some "no notification time" and don't see for example new e-mails coming in.

Would this be possible to archieve? Can an app control this behaviour for other app's?

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers!

Best regards,

Koen

Comment: Are you looking for an AppStore publication? Because if that's the case, you won't be allowed to do so. There shouldn't be any public API to do that. Maybe a private one.

Comment: Just curious - why you need a separate app? You can write code in those 2 apps to block internet access during said time.. You can refer to this link for couple of solutions provided most of them talk about passing data between apps.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425706/share-data-between-two-or-more-iphone-applications , You can write a webservice etc where all 3 apps can communicate

Comment: As everyone has said, the answer is of course, No.

Comment: @AmodGokhale : well I don't know how to set a timer to snooze all notifications between a set of hours, so therefor I was thinking about an app to manage this. I had this feeling that this was not really possible for security matters, and it seems now that indeed it isn't.

Comment: @denappel - you should be able to configure that within app. If that is sole purpose of your query then you don't need separate app, can handle that within app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. Apple "sandboxes" apps so that they have no ability to change the behavior of other apps.

If you **did** find a way to do that, Apple would reject your app, and probably quickly update the OS to prevent whatever method you used to do it.

### EDIT:

You might be able to find a way to do this for jailbroken devices, but obviously those can't be released to the App store.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I thought that this would be the case. I'm not interested in jail breaking my device, so I guess that doesn't give me an option.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, Such Apps are not allowed to be published on App Store.

I have worked with private-apis, and i know that this is not possible with only private apis. This may be possible once after you jailbreak your phone + using private libs, and may be you can create tweaks for jailbreak to achieve this functionality.