# how can a file written into the MyDocuments directory by a Visual Studio Xamarin.IOS app be read by an Xcode Objective-C app?

Tags: ios, .net, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

The Xamarin app writes a file to its 'sandbox' in the MyDocuments directory.
How do I configure the Xamarin app's project to allow another app to read this file; to expose the MyDocuments directory to another app?
How do I configure get the path for the Obj-C app to read the file?

Xamarin app is a .NET Standard 2.0 class lib project in Visual Studio.

BACKGROUND...
The Xamarin app receives BLE data and writes it to files in its MyDocuments directory.
The Obj-C app must read these files and process.

The new IOS 11 File App was suggested as an answer, however I don't think the File App has anything to do with my question because I want my Xcode Obj-C app to programmatically read the file that was written by my Xamarin.IOS app.

Xamarin app's code for writing the file..........................

```
    Sub append_text_file( pathname as string , text_to_file as string)

        dim documents as string = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)

        dim platform_agnostic_pathname as string  = Path.Combine (documents, pathname )
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText( platform_agnostic_pathname, text_to_file)      
End Sub
```

Another great resource:
App Group Capabilities in Xamarin.iOS at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/capabilities/app-groups-capabilities
...I USED SAFARI ON MACBOOK.  IT DOESN'T WORK WITH CHROME ON WINDOWS.

Comment: If both apps are from the same developer (i.e. they use the same group bunder id ( `App Group ID` )  and are signed by the same cert), you can write/read files to their `SharedLocationPath`

Comment: Thanks.  How do I get SharedLocationPath  ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1412643-containerurlforsecurityapplicati (read the **`Discussion`** section)  /  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27730754/4984832

Comment: Thanks, Sushi.  You've really kicked me forward.