# iOS application - How to package resources (nibs, images, sounds, etc.) to reuse later in multiple apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, resources, xib, libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS apps sharing assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662344/ios-apps-sharing-assets)

I am trying to create a unique "About me" section for my iOS apps that I can reuse later in my other apps.

In order to minimize the amount of maintenance work needed to maintain the "About" section of my apps I'm trying to find the best way to create a "library" that would contain the code as well as the xibs/images/sounds for this section that I can simply "drag and drop" in all my apps.

Now I thought about using static libraries, but they do not allow for the use of xib/resource files - so it doesn't seem to be an option.
I could add the resources manually from the library using "Copy Bundles Resources", but I will have quite a few sound effects, images and xib in this section so it doesn't seem to be very practical.

Can someone please tell me what is the preferred way of doing this?

> **ANSWER**

As Vladimir suggested below, this tutorial works in this case:
[galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources](http://galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources)

UPDATE: Using bundles like that, I was unable to "Archive" an app for submission to the appstore. Something to consider before using bundles...
But there have been examples of people using them successfully.

Comment: you can try this tutorial: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/

Comment: @Vladimir, you can write that as aun answer, I would vote it up.

Comment: Please do Vladimir, I will as well.
It just worked like a charm and is very much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why the question was closed as the "duplicate" is about sharing assets dynamically between several apps at the same time (a shared space for different apps), whereas the question I asked was about having 1 compiled package/library with "static" assets to reuse in multiple apps (without the need for a shared space).